# How to create a TreeView with child nodes of different UI Controls

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, treeview

In my program I have a `treeView` for which I want to allow child nodes that are `comboBoxes` and `textBlocks`. My `treeView` along with it's nodes are created in an MVVM style. I know how to create `textBlock` child nodes, but have never created child nodes of any other UI tool.

My `treeview's` xaml:

```
TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding UserControl_DataModel.TreeViewViewModel.ObservableCollection<TreeViewDataModel>}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName.Value".../>
```

This is where new nodes are created and added to the `TreeView` (TreeViewViewModel):

```
private TreeViewDataModel createNewNode(string nodeName)
{
    var newNode = new TreeViewDataModel ()
    {
        DisplayName = nodeName
    };

    newNode.Children.Add(new TreeViewDataModel () { DisplayName = nodeName});

    return newNode;
}

public void addNewLocNode(string nodeName)
{
    TreeObservableCollection.Add(createNewNode(nodeName));
}
```

How do I create child nodes that are `ComboBoxes`, while still allowing the `textblock` children? This confuses me, because I don't see any part of the code that specifies what UI tool the children become. Please let me know if you need to see more code.

([Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24702535/treeview-not-displaying-children-stored-in-data) about this same `treeView` if you need to reference it.)

**Update:**

Just for clarity, this is how my `treeView` nodes should look:

[image]

When I try something like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Data:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndividualProperty}" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionProperty}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I instead get this setup (it's like each item of the tree comes with a `TextBlock` and a `ComboBox`. Maybe there is another option besides `StackPanel`?):

[image]

Note that the `comboBox` is not a child of the `textBlock` node, but it's more like it's on the same level as the `textBlock` node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ComboBox` is a collection control. Therefore, you need a collection property in your 'node' object to bind to the `ComboBox.ItemsSource`. While an individual property in the 'node' object might need a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` somewhat like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Data:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndividualProperty}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

You would need one more like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Data:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionProperty}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Or perhaps like this:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Data:Node}" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding IndividualProperty}" />
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionProperty}" />
    </StackPanel>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This seems to be leading me in the right direction. However, I do have some questions (I'm using the last example btw, because each `ComboBox` has to have a title `textBlock` above it). It seems that the `textBlock` doesn't get displayed at all, even though I am setting it like I was before. Why is this?

Comment: How could I know that?

Comment: Because I'm guessing that it has to do with the `HierarchicalDataTemplate`, since the `TextBlock` children were being displayed before I changed it.

Comment: Sorry, but a 'HierarchicalDataTemplate' is not much more than a `DataTemplate` with an `ItemsSource` property. Using one doesn't affect data binding syntax or paths. You must have some other problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I believe the problem to be with the `StackPanel` part of this example. `StackPanel` doesn't exactly edit the child nodes, instead it kind if "adds" to the current node, like I wrote in my update above. Is there another option I could use besides `StackPanel`?

Comment: A `Grid`, or any other layout `Panel`? Although that won't make any difference to the data binding either. This question has been answered and you are now talking about a different data binding problem, so I suggest that you mock up a small, but complete code example that exhibits this behaviour and add a new question, perhaps linking to this one for background.

Comment: I guess I have "technically" added a `ComboBox` and a `Textblock` to this `TreeView`. Therefore, the question has been answered. I'll write another question up then, because I would like it to behave a little bit differently.